# Import moment.js partial or function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

Is there any way to avoid importing the whole library and import only a function or partial of it?

For example with lodash you can do something like this: `import has from 'lodash/has';`

Example would be:

```
import moment from 'moment';
moment.months()
```

I know the latest webpack can handle it automatically, but question is for old webpack (1.0)

Comment: have you tried `import { months } from 'moment'`

Comment: What's the purpose? Do you want to tree-shake the library or what?

Comment: @SuryaPurohit This obviously won't work. `moment` is default export.

Comment: I just don't want to import the whole library because of one or two functions. Tree-shaking comes from webpack 2.

Comment: @estus Have you tried it? I've tried and after that I am saying it. It's an object having keys. How can be not able to access then?

Comment: Thanks, it looks good and as there is no way yet to import each function separately, I will go with it.

Comment: Please check https://es6console.com/j0z9dg5j/ . The es5 conversion will give you more idea what I am talking about. :)

Comment: @SuryaPurohit This depends on how Webpack is configured. It won't tree-shake anything. And it won't work if Moment is used as ES6 module - because it [doesn't export anything but default](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/moment.js#L82). Even if it will work through CJS hack that es6console offers by default, it is not semantically correct to do that.

Comment: You can't do that with Moment. Lodash was designed as decoupled library (it is available as `lodash.*` packages). Moment wasn't. You will have the whole library in your bundle any way.

Comment: yes, that is true, technically what @SuryaPurohit proposed is the same as the example in the question. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @estus I've used it as ES6 module but it is working. When an object is exported with default, we can access it's keys like that. It's working too, if you are talking about any other scenario please let me know.

Comment: @Shota is that what you needed or you were in a need of something else?

Comment: Yes, it is working, my point was that it still imports the whole library. However good thing is that, it looks nicer :)

Comment: @SuryaPurohit We can't access the keys from `default` export like that in ES6 module. In order for them to be accessed , they should be named exports, `export months ...` (and they aren't). The code you've shown works just because it falls back to CJS module - and the way it works always depends on how build tool was configured. And also, it is not possible to tree-shake anything from CJS modules.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible for moment..
You can do some plugin:
https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2373